# Creating a phase vocoder with the webaudio API using analyzer and periodic wave

Tags: signal-processing, web-audio-api

I was wondering if it would be possible to poll the [AnalyzerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode) from the WebAudio API and use it to construct a [PeriodicWave](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PeriodicWave) that is synthesized via an [OscillatorNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OscillatorNode)?

My intuition is that something about the difference in amplitudes between analyzer frames can help calculate the right phase for a PeriodicWave, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing it. Any help on the right algorithm to use would be appreciated!

Comment: Is recovering the original phases the stumbling block here? If it would be helpful, I can provide an answer re: how to synthesize a phase-randomized version of the original waveform using an AnalyserNode and PeriodicWave/Oscillator, but unfortunately I can't help you with the phase recovery problem.

Comment: That'd be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Sure thing... I'm a bit busy at the moment but I'll write up an answer later today.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... was busier than I expected. Just left an answer below!

Answer (score 2):

As luck would have it, I was working on a similar project just a few weeks ago. I put together a JSFiddle to explore the idea of reconstructing a phase-randomized version of a waveform using frequency data from an AnalyserNode. You can find that experiment here:

https://jsfiddle.net/mattdiamond/w4u7x8zk/

Here's the code that takes in the frequency data output from an AnalyserNode and generates a PeriodicWave:

```js
function generatePeriodicWave(freqData) {
  const real = [];
  const imag = [];

  freqData.forEach((x, i) => {
    const amp = fromDecibels(x);
    const phase = getRandomPhase();
    real.push(amp * Math.cos(phase));
    imag.push(amp * Math.sin(phase));
  });

  return context.createPeriodicWave(real, imag);
}

function fromDecibels(x) {
  return 10 ** (x / 20);
}

function getRandomPhase() {
  return Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI - Math.PI;
}
```

Since the AnalyserNode converts the FFT amplitude values to decibels, we need to recover those original values first (which we do by simply using the inverse of the formula that was used to convert them to decibels). We also need to provide a phase for each frequency, which we select at random from the range -π to π.

Now that we have an amplitude and phase, we construct a complex number by multiplying the amplitude by the cosine and sine of the phase. This is because the amplitude and phase correspond to a polar coordinate, and `createPeriodicWave` expects a list of real and imaginary numbers corresponding to Cartesian coordinates in the complex plane. ([See here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) for more information on the mathematics behind this conversion.)

Once we've generated the PeriodicWave, all that's left to do is load it into an OscillatorNode, set the desired frequency, and start the oscillator. You'll notice that the default frequency is set to `context.sampleRate / FFT_SIZE` (you can ignore the `toFixed`, that was just for the sake of the UI). This causes the oscillator to play the wave at the same rate as the original samples. Increasing or decreasing the frequency from this value will pitch-shift the audio up or down, respectively.

You'll also notice that I chose 2^15 as the FFT size, which is the maximum size that the AnalyserNode allows. For my purposes -- creating interesting looped drones -- a larger FFT results in a more interesting and less "loopy" drone. (A while back I created [a webpage](http://matt-diamond.com/fft.html) that allowed users to generate drones from much larger FFTs... that experiment utilized a third-party FFT library instead of the AnalyserNode.) I'm not sure if this is the right FFT size for your purposes, but it's something to consider.

Anyway, I think that covers the core of the algorithm. Hope this helps! (And feel free to ask more questions in the comments if anything's unclear.)

Comment: I'm going to experiment with this, and one thing I'll try will be using windowing to make it dynamic.

Comment: No problem... one other thing I forgot to mention: if you haven't already, you should consider adjusting the AnalyserNode's smoothingTimeConstant parameter (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/smoothingTimeConstant).